# Chromium doesn't start

Tags: 16.04, chromium

When I use chromium-browser this happen

```
$ chromium-browser
[15136:15170:0301/012914.214743:FATAL:nss_util.cc(631)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found that this might help, but it did not work:

```
$ chromium-browser --disable-extensions
[15208:15242:0301/013019.381998:FATAL:nss_util.cc(631)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I use launcher the icon shows in the dock, then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure chromium is the same architecture as your computer (64bit, 32bit)
If that doesent work delete chromium and run `sudo apt-get update` then reinstall it. That should work